# cardano-wallet for pab-local-cluster

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli, plutus-pab

Does anyone have an example of how to execute the cardano-wallet CLI for the pab-local-cluster in plutus-apps (tag: v2022-01-17)?  I can get access to to the local wallet server APIs, but I need the cardano-wallet CLI so I can create new wallets.   I am running the local cluster as per "cabal exec plutus-pab-local-cluster" but do not see how to execute the cardano-wallet CLI that can connect with the local wallet server that is running.

Comment: Are you working using `nix-shell`? If you have `Nix` and call `nix-shell` first in `plutus-apps` dir, it will load shell where `cardano-wallet` CLI will be available, and you can `cabal build/exec/etc` from there also.

(also, you can create wallets using REST API as well)

Comment: Hi @MikhailLazarev, thanks for the repsonse.   
Yes, I am using nix and when in the nix-shell, can access the cardano-wallet CLI, but it is not connected to the local cluster.   
I've tried to add some params to cardano-wallet serve, but it is unable to connect to the node. The REST API works.     
cardano-wallet serve --node-socket /run/user/1000/test-cluster3561/node/node.socket --testnet /run/user/1000/test-cluster5446/node/byron-genesis.json
[cardano-wallet.network:Warning:27] [2022-01-26 19:46:51.18 UTC] Couldn't connect to node (x19). Retrying in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - I got the cadano-wallet CLI to work with the pab-local-cluster on ubuntu linux, I just setup a simple proxy as per below.

$ simpleproxy -L localhost:8090 -R localhost:46493

Comment: That's good. Can you explain about port 46493? in your answer.

Comment: This is the default port used for cardano wallet server with the local pab cluster.